# Spring Rest Data interceptor to manipulate model object

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Rest Data to expose models as REST api. Depending on the request method (GET/POST) I have to manipulate the model.

What is the best way to manipulate the object during GET/POST requests? Is there any kind of interceptor that I can use to manipulate it (I did not find anything on the official documentation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Controller** to manipulate data before it is persisted. The following should demonstrate how this works:

http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/